# Using d3 javascript with asp.net (VB) to create a graph

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, d3.js

I am new to Asp.Net and hence this place is like a treasure of knowledge for me.

So here is my problem. I have written a javascript code based on D3js with my HTML part. I have a button which helps me calculate two values (based on VB.Net). I want to use those two values along with the javascript code to create a graph. Should I put the javascript within a function and just call that function on the server side (in this case using Vb.Net ) ?

I am just stuck and dont know what else to do. All your help will be highly appreciated. I could add the code snippet if it could help.

Here is my code snippet

```
For i = 0 To carry.Count - 1
carry.Add(trap.AddHours(timeLapse(i)))
  Next
```

where 'carry', is an array list which I wish to use in a javascript that has D3 features associated with it. Currently the javascript code is within my html and the 'carry' is calculated once a button on the form is clicked

Comment: yes, please add a minimal example that illustrates the problem

Comment: @explunit : I think i should pass them to hidden field and then access it through javascript. Do you know of any other way ?

Comment: If the button is calling .net code using a GET or POST request, you could just have the button call a JavaScript function which then uses a d3.json or d3.xml call to load in the response data from the .net function and use that to update your graph.